# how to create unique pandas dataframes while iterating over a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, iteration

With the following list and dataframe I would like to iterate over the list of dates and create a new dataframe for each date that is in the list and dataframe.

list:

```
['12/12/2017', '12/13/2017', '12/14/2017']
```

dataframe:

```
source  time        date
0      a  8:00  12/12/2017
1      b  9:00  12/13/2017
2      c  8:30  12/12/2017
3      b  8:05  12/14/2017
4      a  8:10  12/13/2017
5      a  8:15  12/12/2017
```

Desired output:

```
source  time        date
0      a  8:00      12/12/2017
2      c  8:30      12/12/2017
5      a  8:15      12/12/2017
```

...and so on for each date.

code:

```
import pandas as pd

unique_dates=['12/12/2017','12/13/2017','12/14/2017']

data=[['a','8:00','12/12/2017'],['b','9:00','12/13/2017'],['c','8:30','12/12/2017'],
      ['b','8:05','12/14/2017'],['a','8:10','12/13/2017'],['a','8:15','12/12/2017']]
headers=['source','time','date']
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=headers)

for item in unique_dates:
    if item in df:
        new_df=df[df['date']==item]
        print(new_df)
```

This gives me no output.  I'm at a loss for how to do this and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving this becomes simple, once you identify it as a good use case for a `groupby` operation. All you need to do is pre-filter with `isin`, and then group and iterate.

```
df_list = [g for _, g in df[df.date.isin(unique_dates)].groupby('date')]
```

If you want a dictionary indexed by date instead, call `dict` on the `groupby` object -

```
df_dict = dict(list(df[df.date.isin(unique_dates)].groupby('date')))
```

Or, using a dict comprehension -

```
df_dict = {i : g for i, g in df[df.date.isin(unique_dates)].groupby('date')}
```

---

```
print(*df_list, sep='\n\n')

  source  time        date
0      a  8:00  12/12/2017
2      c  8:30  12/12/2017
5      a  8:15  12/12/2017

  source  time        date
1      b  9:00  12/13/2017
4      a  8:10  12/13/2017

  source  time        date
3      b  8:05  12/14/2017
```